# str_extract regex with quotes and semicolons

Tags: r, regex, string, stringi

I am parsing long strings with semicolons and quotes using R v4.0.0 and `stringi`. Here is an example string:

```r
tstr1 <- 'gene_id "APE_RS08740"; transcript_id "unassigned_transcript_1756"; gbkey "CDS"; inference "COORDINATES: protein motif:HMM:NF014037.1"; locus_tag "APE_RS08740"; note "incomplete; partial in the middle of a contig; missing N-terminus"; partial "true"; product "DUF5615 family PIN-like protein"; pseudo "true"; transl_table "11"; exon_number "1"'
```

I would like to extract a quoted substring by first matching a variable pattern `var` and then extracting everything until the next semicolon. I would like to avoid matching instances of `var` that are within quoted substrings. So far, I have this:

```r
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
var <- "partial"
str_extract(string = tstr1, pattern = paste0('"; ', var, '[^;]+')) %>%
    gsub(paste0("\"; ", var), "", .) %>%
    gsub("\"", "", .) %>% trimws()
```

This returns `"true"`, which is my desired output.  However, I need a regex that also works in two edge cases:

##### Case 1

When `var` is at the beginning of the string and I can't rely on a preceding `";`  to match.

```r
tstr2 <- 'partial "true"; gene_id "APE_RS08740"; transcript_id "unassigned_transcript_1756"; gbkey "CDS"; infernce "COORDINATES: protein motif:HMM:NF014037.1"; locus_tag "APE_RS08740"; note "incomplete; partial in the middle of a contig; missing N-terminus"; product "DUF5615 family PIN-like protein"; pseudo "true"; transl_table "11"; exon_number "1"'
```

Expected output: `"true"`

##### Case 2

When the quoted substring to be extracted contains a semicolon, I would want to match everything until the next semicolon *that is not within the quoted substring*.

```r
tstr3 <- 'partial "true; foo"; gene_id "APE_RS08740"; transcript_id "unassigned_transcript_1756"; gbkey "CDS"; infernce "COORDINATES: protein motif:HMM:NF014037.1"; locus_tag "APE_RS08740"; note "incomplete; partial in the middle of a contig; missing N-terminus"; product "DUF5615 family PIN-like protein"; pseudo "true"; transl_table "11"; exon_number "1"'
```

Expected output: `"true; foo"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use an OR (`|`) condition for cases where the 'partial' doesn't have any preceding `"` or `;`, and then extract the characters between the two `"`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(tstr, sprintf('";\\s+%1$s[^;]+|^%1$s[^;]+;[^"]+"', var)) %>% 
     trimws(whitespace = '["; ]+', which = 'left') %>% 
      str_extract('(?<=")[^"]+(?=")')
```

-output

```
[1] "true"      "true"      "true; foo"
```

#### data

```
tstr <- c(tstr1, tstr2, tstr3)
```

Comment: +1, This works great for the provided example, but could you edit your answer to make it generalizable to `var` and not the specific instance `var <- "partial"`?

Comment: @acvill added with `sprintf` to insert the 'var'